Bezier surface matrix form
I have a problem with constructing a Bezier surface following an example from a book, using mathematical formulas in matrix form.
Especially when multiplying matrices.
I'm trying to use this formula
I have a matrix of control points
B = np.array([
    [[-15, 0, 15], [-15, 5, 5], [-15, 5, -5], [-15, 0, -15]], 
    [[-5, 5, 15], [-5, 5, 5], [-5, 5, -5], [-5, 5, -15]], 
    [[5, 5, 15], [5, 5, 5], [5, 5, -5], [5, 5, -15]], 
    [[15, 0, 15], [15, 5, 5], [15, 5, -5], [15, 0, -15]]
])

And we have to multiply it by matrices
and get [N][B][N]^t
And I tried to multiply the matrix by these two, but I get completely different values ​​for the final matrix, I understand that most likely the problem is in the code
"
B = np.array([
    [[-15, 0, 15], [-5, 5, 15], [5, 5, 15], [15, 0, 15]], 
    [[-15, 5, 5], [-5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5], [15, 5, 5]], 
    [[-15, 5, -5], [-5, 5, -5], [5, 5, -5], [15, 5, -5]], 
    [[-15, 0, -15], [-5, 5, -15], [5, 5, -15], [15, 0, -15]]
])

N = np.array([[-1, 3, -3, 1],
               [3, -6, 3, 0],
               [-3, 3, 0, 0],
               [1, 0, 0, 0]
              ])

Nt = np.array([[-1, 3, -3, 1],
               [3, -6, 3, 0],
               [-3, 3, 0, 0],
               [1, 0, 0, 0]])


B_transformed = np.zeros_like(B)


for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[1]): 
        for k in range(3): 
            
            B_transformed[i, j, k] = B[i, j, k] * N[j, k] * Nt[j, k]

"
 [[[ -15    0  135]
  [ -45  180  135]
  [  45   45    0]
  [  15    0    0]]

 [[ -15   45   45]
  [ -45  180   45]
  [  45   45    0]
  [  15    0    0]]

 [[ -15   45  -45]
  [ -45  180  -45]
  [  45   45    0]
  [  15    0    0]]

 [[ -15    0 -135]
  [ -45  180 -135]
  [  45   45    0]
  [  15    0    0]]]

Correct answer from book is
NBNt = np.array([
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, -45, 0], [0, 45, 0], [0, -15, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 45, 0], [0, -45, 0], [30, 15, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, -15, 0], [0, 15, -30], [-15, 0, 15]]
])

Next, matrix multiplication will also be performed, so it’s important for me to understand what I’m doing wrong
Q(0.5, 0.5) =
[0.125 0.25  0.5   1.   ] * [N][B][N]^t * [[0.125]
                                           [0.25 ]
                                           [0.5  ]
                                           [1.   ]]

This is the calculation of a point on a surface at w = 0.5 and u = 0.5
And the answer should be
[0, 4.6875, 0]
I use Jupyter Notebook

Welcome to SO! Really nice first question! Happy coding!

Generally, Bezier surface are plotted this way (as the question is posted in matplotlib).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.special import comb

def bernstein_poly(i, n, t):
    return comb(n, i) * (t**i) * ((1 - t)**(n - i))

def bernstein_matrix(n, t):
    return np.array([bernstein_poly(i, n, t) for i in range(n + 1)])

P = np.array([
    [[-15, 0, 15], [-15, 5, 5], [-15, 5, -5], [-15, 0, -15]], 
    [[-5, 5, 15], [-5, 5, 5], [-5, 5, -5], [-5, 5, -15]], 
    [[5, 5, 15], [5, 5, 5], [5, 5, -5], [5, 5, -15]], 
    [[15, 0, 15], [15, 5, 5], [15, 5, -5], [15, 0, -15]]
])

n, m = P.shape[0] - 1, P.shape[1] - 1

u = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
v = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)

surface_points = np.zeros((U.shape[0], U.shape[1], 3))
for i in range(U.shape[0]):
    for j in range(U.shape[1]):
        Bu = bernstein_matrix(n, U[i, j])
        Bv = bernstein_matrix(m, V[i, j])
        surface_points[i, j] = np.tensordot(np.tensordot(Bu, P, axes=(0, 0)), Bv, axes=(0, 0))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(surface_points[:,:,0], surface_points[:,:,1], surface_points[:,:,2], rstride=1, cstride=1, color='b', alpha=0.6, edgecolor='w')
ax.scatter(P[:,:,0], P[:,:,1], P[:,:,2], color='r', s=50)

plt.show()


which return

Now, for your particular problem, you can do this:
import numpy as np

B = np.array([
    [[-15, 0, 15], [-15, 5, 5], [-15, 5, -5], [-15, 0, -15]], 
    [[-5, 5, 15], [-5, 5, 5], [-5, 5, -5], [-5, 5, -15]], 
    [[5, 5, 15], [5, 5, 5], [5, 5, -5], [5, 5, -15]], 
    [[15, 0, 15], [15, 5, 5], [15, 5, -5], [15, 0, -15]]
])

N = np.array([[-1, 3, -3, 1],
              [3, -6, 3, 0],
              [-3, 3, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0]])

Nt = N.T

B_transformed = np.zeros((4, 4, 3))

for i in range(3):  
    B_transformed[:, :, i] = N @ B[:, :, i] @ Nt

print("Transformed control points matrix B_transformed:")
print(B_transformed)

u = 0.5
w = 0.5

U = np.array([u**3, u**2, u, 1])
W = np.array([w**3, w**2, w, 1])

Q = np.array([U @ B_transformed[:, :, i] @ W for i in range(3)])

print("Point on the Bézier surface Q(0.5, 0.5):")
print(Q)


which gives you
Transformed control points matrix B_transformed:
[[[  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0. -45.   0.]
  [  0.  45.   0.]
  [  0. -15.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  45.   0.]
  [  0. -45.   0.]
  [ 30.  15.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.]
  [  0. -15.   0.]
  [  0.  15. -30.]
  [-15.   0.  15.]]]
Point on the Bézier surface Q(0.5, 0.5):
[0.     4.6875 0.    ]

and if you also want to plot it, you can adapt my top code to this:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.special import comb

def bernstein_poly(i, n, t):
    return comb(n, i) * (t**i) * ((1 - t)**(n - i))

def bernstein_matrix(n, t):
    return np.array([bernstein_poly(i, n, t) for i in range(n + 1)])

B = np.array([
    [[-15, 0, 15], [-15, 5, 5], [-15, 5, -5], [-15, 0, -15]], 
    [[-5, 5, 15], [-5, 5, 5], [-5, 5, -5], [-5, 5, -15]], 
    [[5, 5, 15], [5, 5, 5], [5, 5, -5], [5, 5, -15]], 
    [[15, 0, 15], [15, 5, 5], [15, 5, -5], [15, 0, -15]]
])

N = np.array([[-1, 3, -3, 1],
              [3, -6, 3, 0],
              [-3, 3, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0]])

Nt = N.T

B_transformed = np.zeros((4, 4, 3))

for i in range(3): 
    B_transformed[:, :, i] = N @ B[:, :, i] @ Nt

print("Transformed control points matrix B_transformed:")
print(B_transformed)

u = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
w = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
U, W = np.meshgrid(u, w)

surface_points = np.zeros((U.shape[0], U.shape[1], 3))
for i in range(U.shape[0]):
    for j in range(U.shape[1]):
        U_vec = np.array([U[i, j]**3, U[i, j]**2, U[i, j], 1])
        W_vec = np.array([W[i, j]**3, W[i, j]**2, W[i, j], 1])
        surface_points[i, j] = np.array([U_vec @ B_transformed[:, :, k] @ W_vec for k in range(3)])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(surface_points[:,:,0], surface_points[:,:,1], surface_points[:,:,2], rstride=1, cstride=1, color='b', alpha=0.6, edgecolor='w')
ax.scatter(B[:,:,0], B[:,:,1], B[:,:,2], color='r', s=50)

plt.show()


giving you again

